# Finding LaTeX in variable?

Tags: regex, perl

In the below script would I like to wrap `$$` around the latex section. Here it would be before `\begin{center}` and after `\end{center}`, but it could be any `\begin{}`/`\end{}` pair.

The raw text at the bottom is in `$f`.

**Question**

Can anyone see why my script inserts too many `$$`?

**My script**

```
my @lines = split "\n", $f;
$f = "";
my $btype = "";
my $flag = 1;
for my $line (@lines) {
   $flag = $1 if $line =~ /\\begin\{(.*?)\}/;
   if ($flag ne 0) {
       $line = "\$\$\n$line";
       $flag = 0;
   }
   $f .= "$line\n";
}
```

**My output**

```
$$
begin:text
# Question intro text for dec04opg10

$$
\begin{center}
$$
\begin{tabular}{l|ccc}
& SURF & VOL & MW \\ \hline
SURF &1 & 0.995 & 0.949 \\
VOL &  0.995 & 1 & 0.952 \\
MW & 0.949 & 0.952 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
end:text

begin:multiple_choice
```

**The raw text**

```
begin:text
# Question intro text for dec04opg10

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|ccc}
& SURF & VOL & MW \\ \hline
SURF &1 & 0.995 & 0.949 \\
VOL &  0.995 & 1 & 0.952 \\
MW & 0.949 & 0.952 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
end:text

begin:multiple_choice
```

**Desired output**

```
begin:text
# Question intro text for dec04opg10

$$
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|ccc}
& SURF & VOL & MW \\ \hline
SURF &1 & 0.995 & 0.949 \\
VOL &  0.995 & 1 & 0.952 \\
MW & 0.949 & 0.952 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
$$
end:text

begin:multiple_choice
```

Comment: Does it insert too many `$$`? The output has three of them. One in front of each `\begin{}`. That's exactly what you said in your question.

Comment: Oh. The `begin:text` does not count.

Comment: I have now add how the output ought to look like.

Comment: So you want the `$$` to be wrapped around the outer-most pair of `\begin` and `\end`?

Comment: Your code adds one `$$` at the beginning (`$flag` is not `0` initially) and one for every `\begin{` `}`. I'm not sure what you were expecting.

Comment: @simbabque Yes, exactly.

Comment: @melpomene I don't understand why it does it before `begin:text` and before every `\begin{}` and not just the first it finds.

Comment: I told you why it does it at the beginning: Because `$flag` is not `0` initially (you set it to `1`). And it happens before `\begin{tabular}` because your regex matches and sets `$flag` to `"tabular"`. Which is also not `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start out with your `$flag` turned off, and you also need to keep track of your `$btype`. You already have the variable, but you are not using it. Since you only want the outermost pair, you need only need to capture the `begin` if you don't have a `$btype` yet.

```
my @lines = split "\n", $f;
$f = "";
my $btype;
my $flag = 0;
for my $line (@lines) {

    # put in the beginning
    if ( not $btype and $line =~ /\\begin\{(.*?)\}/ ) {
        $flag  = 1;
        $btype = $1;
    }
    if ($flag) {
        $line = "\$\$\n$line";
        $flag = 0;
    }

    # now use $btype to find the end ...

    $f .= "$line\n";
}
```

This outputs

```
begin:text
# Question intro text for dec04opg10

$$
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|ccc}
& SURF & VOL & MW \\ \hline
SURF &1 & 0.995 & 0.949 \\
VOL &  0.995 & 1 & 0.952 \\
MW & 0.949 & 0.952 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
end:text

begin:multiple_choice
```